# Como adicionar licença para meu aplicativo python?

Tags: python, segurança, licença

Estou tendo um problema.Esse problema é "Como criar uma licença para o meu software".

Suponha que essa é a minha chave de licença - 12345YW

Quando o usuário digitar essa chave de licença, o software deverá permitir que ele use o software. Tudo bem, depois que o usuário digita a chave de licença, meu software deve se lembrar de que ele inseriu a chave válida, certo? (Porque da próxima vez em diante, ele não precisará abrir o diálogo de licença) Minha pergunta é: Como posso desenvolver isso?É possível de fazer?

De novo peço que quem está negativando minhas perguntas deixe nos comentários o que quer alterar.Só negativar não vai me fazer entender o que não gostou.

Answer (score 5):

Uma forma 100% garantida de fazer isso não existe.
No entanto, dá para criar a coisa de forma que sem fazer uma engenharia reversa do seu código a pessoa não tenha como usar - e se fizer, vai saber que está violando o contrato de cessão do software e sujeito a ser acionado na justiça.

O mais tranquilo, se você vai optar por esse modelo de negócio, seria manter o "núcleo" do seu software, a parte que provê valor mesmo, na nuvem - e aí, se o usuário está com a licença em atraso, você bloqueia o login e resolvido. Dados sobre pagamento, etc...ficam nos seus servidores e não tem dor de cabeça. Isso não obriga que o software seja web - você pode desenvolver uma interface em Python também, usando Qt ou outra biblioteca de sua preferência, e só delegar o processamento das funções críticas (e possivelmente armazenamento de dados) aos seus servidores. Mas também pode criar uma interface 100% web e manter todo o software do seu lado.

Dito isso, a primeira coisa: se o seu cliente tiver os arquivos .py doseu programa, que é a forma preferida de disponibilizar softwares complexos em Python (mesmo que em paralelo haja uma distribuição "standalone" binária), fica trivial achar o caminho bloqueado pela falta da licença e alterar o sistema para não precisar dela. Então você tem que criar uma distribuição standalone, uma sugestão é usar o [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/), ou mesmo o [nuitka](http://nuitka.net/) (o primeiro empacota o executável do Python e todos os módulos que você usa num "zip" que é transformado num executável, o segundo de fato compila seu código Python para código nativo e integra o interpretador - em tese é mais fácil 'descompilar' o primeiro - mas talvez existam opções criptográficas que dificultem um pouco esse processo).

Depois disso, manter a licença já digitada uma vez, é algo trivial: use um arquivo numa localização conhecida. Já que a senha é conhecida do seu usuário, em é problema ela estar em "plaintext"  nesse arquivo - mas você pode maquiar a mesma com uma função criptográfica. Pode também usar funções do sistema operacional, para criar uma entrada no "registry" no caso do Windows e deixar o valor lá.

Ao iniciar o programa, é trivial: você tenta primeiro ler a licença desse ponto de armazenagem externo - se ela não existir, ou for inválida, você apresenta o diálogo pedindo a mesma, como descreveu.

Talvez uma forma viável de manter o controle de acesso em software que esteja local no cliente, seja separado código crítico da sua aplicação em um módulo ou pacote, e, mesmo na distribuição standalone, guardar o código fonte dessa parte do código como uma string criptografada. A senha para descriptografar essa string pode se a própria licença de uso, ou, preferencialmente, uma derivada da licença de uso e nome do usuário do programa (daí se ele copia o programa para um terceiro, quaisquer relatórios, etc...vão sair com o nome do primeiro licenciado) - e no momento da execução, depois de obter a licença, como descrito acima, você descriptografa essa parte do código e usa a função `compile` do Python - só aí essa parte do programa vai estar disponível para uso. Ainda não é 100% seguro - o usuário poderá dar um jeito de abrir um prompt de depuração no seu programa, e gravar o bytecode protegido num arquivo externo, etc..mas começa a ficar mais complicado.

Para você ter uma ideia, o Dropbox, a empresa que empregou o próprio Guido van Rossum nos últimos anos (ele anunciou sua aposentadoria recentemente), é uma das distribuições de software feito em Python para uso local, e que é bem protegido contra engenharia reversa - e eles mesmos levaram algum tempo, e várias pessoas trabalhando no problema, antes de chegar numa solução para isso.

Por isso comecei dizendo que a operação em nuvem pode ser mais simples.

Comment: eu usei o pyinstaller e funcionou certinho

Comment: Não precisa ser 100% seguro.O aplicativo não envolve transações bancárias ou algo do tipo.É um simples gravador de tela.